# Split a string into three parts that does not have a delimiter (Java)

Tags: java

I have a `String`

```
String test = "7462356098660AE";
```

I want to split it into:

```
test1 = "746";
test2 = "2356";
test3 = "0986";
test4 = "60AE";
```

The length of the String `test` will be always the same.

How will I be able to do this?

PS: I have checked other questions but couldn't find a suitable answer.

Comment: Is the format of the string always the same?

Comment: Have you tried java.lang.String.substring()?

Comment: what is your rules to split this String? because we can split a String in many parts using different rules...

Comment: So much hate and downvotes for newbie questions. :(  It's an innocent question, and not a terrible one at that.  It shows thought at least as far as "...but it doesn't have delimiters.  Hm!"

Comment: @Jeff: it's not a *great* question and would never have gotten 4 upvotes that quickly, were it not for the downvotes. So it's a net-win on the reputation front ;-)

Comment: @Jeff For the record, reading the entire `String` javadoc page is required reading for any beginner. And not just that page, of course.

Comment: @JoachimSauer I'm not particularly concerned with anyone's reputation, just the general atmosphere of SO. :)

Comment: @MarkTopolnik Maybe, but for beginner programmers much of what is contained in Javadoc is too technical to be accessible.  Javadoc is created for the audience of experienced programmers who already know something.  A tutorial might be more appropriate.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
String test = "7462356098660AE";
String test1 = test.substring(0,3);
String test2 = test.substring(3,7);
String test3 = test.substring(7,11);
String test4 = test.substring(11,15);
```

Comment: The OP would probably benefit from an explanation of the method more than just writing the code for him, since he seems to be a beginner programmer. :)

Comment: I didn't know of substring() method. This helped me. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 4):

For convenience, you can write this kind of Splitter class:

```
public class Splitter {
  private final int[] borders;
  private final String s;
  public Splitter(String s, int... borders) {
    this.s = s;
    this.borders = borders;
  }
  public String seg(int seg) {
    return s.substring(seg == 0? 0 : borders[seg-1], borders[seg]);
  }
}
```

You'd use it like this:

```
final Splitter splitter = new Splitter("7462356098660AE", 3, 7, 11, 15);
for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) System.out.println(splitter.seg(i));
```

Answer (score 2):

Not sure what your use case is here, but if the substring of code are always the same length, you could use the [`substring()` method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring%28int,%20int%29). You just give it the beginning and ending index of the substring you want.

Comment: I didn't know of substring() method. This helped me. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

If the string is fixed width for all of the fields you want, you could use the substring/subSequence methods of String, or your could create regular expression and grabs the values of the capturing groups.